# RecyclerView data sync between UI thread and update thread

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My app has 2 threads. UI thread allows user view detail item, delete item, change item property, ... And 1 thread update data from server, then request UI thread refresh `RecyclerView`. Every update data, I call method `clear()` of `ArrayList` and update `ArrayList` with new data from server. This make `IndexOutOfBoundsException` If I interact with `RecyclerView` when thread 2nd is updating data.

So on `Activity`, in `dispatchTouchEvent()` I wait until update data complete to enable user interaction. An when user interact to `RecyclerView` I set 1 `boolean` value to disable thread 2nd update data. But sometime exception trigger. Are there any better solution for this?

Comment: you have to synchronize data model changes between threads, but the easiest way is to update your data from UI thread by means of `android.os.Handler`

Comment: In my case, There were multiple places which  fetch and prepares the list update the list used by recycler view, for a performance improvement task, I put the parts - ( preprocessing, preparation of the data , and diff utils calculations and the update part ) in IO thread and only the notifydatasetChanged or dispatchUpdatesTo part in Main thread, But later it started giving those error related to recyclerview list in inconsistent state, becasue of mutiplpe methods trying to update the list.
yes, Its a synchronisation proble.

Comment: We have reverted some code to fix - all the list operation diffutils cal, update list in main thread.
Correct fix would be to use synchronisation on list while having the better performance with delegating maximum works to IO thread.

How did you finally resolve your issues @cxphong

Answer (score 1):

try using synchronized object. something like 
synchronized("abc") { updateFromThread1();}
synchronized("abc") { updateFromThread2(); }

Comment: this is not how this should be dealt with

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach would be to simply either `try/catch` the code block where that exception can happen or check if the index you want to reach prior using it.